# Controlling window movement by mouse

Tags: javascript, html

How do I control a window by mouse movement in javascript?? I mean the page should auto scroll on moving the mouse.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6518600/scroll-window-when-mouse-moves

Comment: yeah, do google before asking questions here, though I have worked with parallax before, the code I pasted below is what I got on googling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done using [parallax](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-parallax-style) like in this http://www.franckmaurin.com/the-parallax-effects-with-jquery/

You are not actually controlling a window but divs.

Here is a sample basic code:

```
// Variables for current position

var x, y;

function handleMouse(e)
{
if (x && y) 
{
   window.scrollBy(e.clientX - x, e.clientY - y);
}
x = e.clientX;
y = e.clientY;
}

document.onmousemove = handleMouse;
```